# tracksTextAttachmentViewBounds not working

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, textkit

I want to have a `UIView` inside of a `UITextView.` For that I use the new `NSTextAttachmentViewProvider` class introduced in iOS 15. The views width should always be equal to the width of the `UITextView` this width should update when, for example, the screen rotates.

To do that I am using the  `tracksTextAttachmentViewBounds` property inside of a `NSTextAttachmentViewProvider` subclass. If I understand correctly, if this property is set to true, the function `attachmentBounds(for:location:textContainer:proposedLineFragment:position:)` of my `NSTextAttachmentViewProvider` subclass should be used to determine the views bounds. In the code example below I have set it up in that manner, sadly the function is never called. (The storyboard consists of a `UIViewController` with a `UITextView` which four constrains (trailing, leading, bottom, top) are set equal to the safe area, nothing special going on). I have also tried to use a `NSTextAttachment` subclass in which I override the `attachmentBounds(for:location:textContainer:proposedLineFragment:position:)` function. It is also not called.
The view is appearing, but not with the width and height that I have set in the function (see screenshot below), maybe it is using some default values. When I start typing, the view disappears.

I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Could somebody help me with that problem?

```
import UIKit

class SomeNSTextAttachmentViewProvider : NSTextAttachmentViewProvider {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        tracksTextAttachmentViewBounds = true
        view = UIView()
        view!.backgroundColor = .purple
    }

    override func attachmentBounds(
        for attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any],
        location: NSTextLocation,
        textContainer: NSTextContainer?,
        proposedLineFragment: CGRect,
        position: CGPoint
    ) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: proposedLineFragment.width, height: 200)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSTextAttachment.registerViewProviderClass(SomeNSTextAttachmentViewProvider.self, forFileType: "public.data")

        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString("purple box: "))
        mutableAttributedString.append(
            NSAttributedString(
                attachment: NSTextAttachment(data: nil, ofType: "public.data")
            )
        )
        textView?.attributedText = mutableAttributedString
        textView?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Works now in iOS 16. Also, `tracksTextAttachmentViewBounds = true` should be moved into an initialiser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
override init(textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, parentView: UIView?, textLayoutManager: NSTextLayoutManager?, location: NSTextLocation) {
    super.init(textAttachment: textAttachment, parentView: parentView, textLayoutManager: textLayoutManager, location: location)
    tracksTextAttachmentViewBounds = true
}
```

Just move `tracksTextAttachmentViewBounds` setter into `init` as [bryanboateng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13788214/bryanboateng) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72568261/1735276).

[attachmentBounds(for:location:textContainer:proposedLineFragment:position:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextattachmentviewprovider/3857594-attachmentbounds) is called before `loadView` gets called, so it makes sense to set variable before it is being used.

This behavior is undocumented, hope Apple will add some details into documentation later.

P.S. I've checked it in iOS 15.0 Simulator - the same code didn't work. This solution works under iOS 16 both on iPhone and in Simulator.